# yii2 kartik grid view pageSummary show total of all data

Tags: yii2

Is there any way to show pageSummary of all data even if there is pagination?

```
[
    'attribute' => 'sale_total',
    'pageSummary' => true,
    'hAlign' => 'right',
    'format' => ['decimal',2],
],
```

This shows only sum per page but I wanted it of all the data, not a particular page.

Answer (score 0):

By Clicking the All(Show all data) link(On the right side toolbar options), the sum of all the records total will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
'summary' => {totalCount},
```

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.